# Fixing jQuery plugin to handle duplicating nested fields with unique ID's

Tags: php, jquery

I have a quick question for you guys here. I was handed a set of lead generation pages and asked to get them up and running. The forms are great, expect for one small issue... they use the jQuery below to allow users to submit multiple instances of a data set by clicking an "Add another item" button. The problem is that the duplicated items are duplicated EXACTLY. Same name, id, etc. Obviously, this doesn't work when attempting to process the data via PHP, as only the first set is used.

I'm still learning jQuery, so I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction for how to modify the plugin below to assign each duplicated field an incremental integer on the end of the ID and name assigned. So, the fields in each dataset are Role, Description, Age. Each additional dataset will use the ID & name syntax of fieldname#, where # represents numbers increasing by 1.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

```js
/** https://github.com/ReallyGood/jQuery.duplicate */
$.duplicate = function(){
  var body = $('body');
  body.off('duplicate');
  var templates = {};
  var settings = {};
  var init = function(){
    $('[data-duplicate]').each(function(){
      var name = $(this).data('duplicate');
      var template = $('<div>').html( $(this).clone(true) ).html();
      var options = {};
      var min = +$(this).data('duplicate-min');
      options.minimum = isNaN(min) ? 1 : min;
      options.maximum = +$(this).data('duplicate-max') || Infinity;
      options.parent = $(this).parent();

      settings[name] = options;
      templates[name] = template;
    });
    
    body.on('click.duplicate', '[data-duplicate-add]', add);
    body.on('click.duplicate', '[data-duplicate-remove]', remove);
  };
  
  function add(){
    var targetName = $(this).data('duplicate-add');
    var selector = $('[data-duplicate=' + targetName + ']');
    var target = $(selector).last();
    if(!target.length) target = $(settings[targetName].parent);
    var newElement = $(templates[targetName]).clone(true);
    
    if($(selector).length >= settings[targetName].maximum) {
      $(this).trigger('duplicate.error');
      return;
    }
    target.after(newElement);
    $(this).trigger('duplicate.add');
  }
  
  function remove(){
    var targetName = $(this).data('duplicate-remove');
    var selector = '[data-duplicate=' + targetName + ']';
    var target = $(this).closest(selector);
    if(!target.length) target = $(this).siblings(selector).eq(0);
    if(!target.length) target = $(selector).last();
    
    if($(selector).length <= settings[targetName].minimum) {
      $(this).trigger('duplicate.error');
      return;
    }
    target.remove();
    $(this).trigger('duplicate.remove');
  }
  
  $(init);
};

$.duplicate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `[]` to the end of the NAME attribute of the input field so for example:

`<input type ="text" name="name[]"`

This way your `$POST['name']` will hold an array of strings. For that element. It will be an array with keys that are numbers from 0 to however many items it holds.